# How many numbers in a given range are coprime to $N$?

Tags: algorithms, coprime

Is there a good algorithm for counting the numbers $x$ between $A$ and $B$ with $x$ and $N$ coprime? This is just like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019040/how-many-numbers-below-n-are-coprimes-to-n) except for the range.

The factorization of $N$ is known. I actually need to solve the problem for fixed $N$ and many ranges, so I think I can mark all multiples of factors of $N$ in a `BitSet` and simply count what remains. But is there a nicer solution (or one for the case I need the answer for a single range only)?

Comment: Yes, you should look into Euler's $\phi$ function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function

Comment: Interesting algorithmic problem! Would suggest inclusion/exclusion to count the ones **not** relatively prime to $N$ if the prime power factorization of $N$ has few primes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $f(C)$ be the number of integers from $1$ to $C$ that are relatively prime to $N$. If we can compute $f(C)$, the rest is easy. Say we are allowing $A \le x\le B$. Then our answer is $f(B)-f(A-1)$.

Note that $f(C)$ is $C$ minus the number of integers in the interval $[1,C]$ that are **not** relatively prime to $N$.

Call this number $g(C)$. So $f(C)=C-g(C)$. We attack the problem of finding $g(C)$.

If $N$ is a prime power $p^a$, it is easy. The numbers in the interval $[1,C]$ that are **not** relatively prime to $N$ are the multiples of $p$. Thus 
$$g(C)=\left\lfloor \frac{C}{p}\right\rfloor,$$
 where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the usual "floor" function.

If $N$ has prime power factorization $p^aq^b$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, then $g(C)$ is the number of integers in $[1,C]$ that are divisible by $p$ or $q$ or **both**. By Inclusion/Exclusion, we obtain
$$g(C)=\left\lfloor \frac{C}{p}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{C}{q}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{C}{pq}\right\rfloor.$$
The reason is that when we add the first two terms above, we are counting twice all the multiples of $pq$.

If $N$ has prime power factorization $p^aq^br^c$, the same basic idea works. We get
$$g(C)=\left\lfloor \frac{C}{p}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{C}{q}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{C}{r}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{C}{qr}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{C}{pr}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{C}{pq}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{C}{pqr}\right\rfloor.$$

Similar expressions work for $N$ that has a more complex prime power factorization.

**Remark:** Depending on the relative sizes of $A$, $B$, and $N$, there are shortcuts available, involving the Euler $\varphi$-function. This is because there are $\varphi(N)$ numbers relatively prime to $N$ in the interval $[kN+1,(k+1)N]$. Since you know the prime power factorization of $N$, $\varphi(N)$ is given by a simple formula.  Thus our problem is solved if we can find $f(D)$ for $D\lt N$. For dividing $C$ by $N$ gives us the number of full "chunks" of shape  $[kN+1,(k+1)N]$ there are up to $C$. These are dealt with using the $\varphi$-function, and the remainder $D$ is dealt with by Inclusion/Exclusion.

And in addition to mathematical facts, one will need programming ideas to produce an efficient solution.

Comment: Very nice answer! The programming ideas are rather trivial: Using a `mask` running from `0` to `numberOfDifferentFactors-1`, compute the `nominator` as product of corresponding primes, depending on `bitCount(mask) & 1` add or subtract `C/nominator`, done.

Comment: Why does it not matter what the power is on $p^aq^b$? It seems you just divide by the base regardless of the power

Comment: Because for coprimality what matters is the presence or absence of the prime, not the power to which it occurs.

Answer (score 7):

For a proof of André Nicolas's formula using multiplicative number theory, see Section 8.3 in I. Niven, H. S. Zuckerman, H. L. Montgomery, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers,* 5th ed., Wiley (New York), 1991, which gives the succinct expressions
\begin{align}
f(C) & = \sum_{d|N} \mu(d) \left\lfloor \frac{C}{d} \right\rfloor\\
     & = \frac{C \varphi(N)}{N} - \sum_{d|N} \mu(d) \text{ frac} \left( \frac{C}{d} \right)
\end{align}
where the sums are taken over the positive square-free integers $d$ that divide $N$ because $\mu(d)$, the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function#Definition), is $0$ when $d$ is not square-free, and $\text{frac}$ is the [fractional part function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part).  We see that $C\varphi(N)/N$ approximates $f(C)$ and that the approximation improves as $C$ increases or as the number of prime factors of $N$ decreases.

Comment: Nice summary, thanks for distilling the ideas of the other answer so well. I've written up a short Haskell implementation of the idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49788622/791604); this algorithm is beautifully concise, even after converting to executable code!